# What is the easiest way to remember where to use "could" and "would" while talking to someone?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, american-english, confusable

Whenever I speak it gets confusing for me where to use "would" and "could". I want some easy tips on how to use it. I mean overall how to use this model verbs for the  past sentences and for the future sentences. And is there any certain genres of books I can read to improve my English speaking vocabulary?

Comment: Is there anything in particular that gives you trouble?  Can you give us some examples?  Otherwise the question is really too broad to answer easily.

Comment: This is probably two separate questions. And the second question is probably off-topic, but can probably be better answered (and asked) at the English Language Learners Meta, [Resources for Learning English](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english).

Answer (score 1):

I could have and I would have, but I can't, so I won't.

> I could have (based on my *assumed* ability in the past) and
>
> I would have (based on my *assumed* willingness in the past), but
>
> I can't (based on my *lack of* ability now), so
>
> I won't (based on my *lack of* willingness now and for the foreseeable future).

Does this help?